# О чем говорит ошибка Strict Standards: mysqli::next_result():

Tags: php, mysqli

Ошибка:

`There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method`

строка имеет вид: `} while ($mysqli->next_result());`

код используется из мануала PHP

```
/* запускаем мультизапрос */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* получаем первый результирующий набор */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* печатаем разделитель */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

запросы стандартные: выбрать поля по id для 10 записей

К сожалению, не могу понять, что именно он хочет.
Кто сталкивался и знает, подскажите решение!?

Comment: хочу заметить, что запрос обрабатывает корректно

Comment: Замените printf на break, а потом распишите на бумаге, как работает ваш цикл. Я серьезно.

Comment: @Etki на самом деле там `echo $row[0];` `echo $row[1];` и т.д. , не думал, что это так важно, поэтому не менял строку с примера с сайта PHP. Так в чем тут дело, конкретно, я вас не понял, будьте добры?

Comment: [Тонкий](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.next-result.php). [Намёк](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.more-results.php).

Comment: @D-side давайте буду угадывать. Проверять существование с помощью mysqli_more_results() прежде чем запускать next_result() ?

Comment: Совершенно верно!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом коде несколько проблем.

Первая, и самая главная - использование multi_query для стандартных запросов выбрать поля по id для 10 записей. Это даже не из пушки по воробьям, это натурально гвозди забивать микроскопом.

Чтобы выбрать поля по id для 10 записей, надо сделать ОДИН запрос:

```
WHERE id IN (1,2,5)
```

Вторая проблема была объяснена в комментариях. Проверять существование с помощью mysqli_more_results() прежде чем запускать next_result().

```
do {
    $result = $mysqli->store_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo $row[0], "\n";
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

Мануал просто еще не обновили.

Еще одна ошибка, связанная с `multi_query()` состоит в том, что эта функция не поддерживает передачу данных в запрос через плейсхолдеры. Которые являются **единственно верным способом передавать переменные в запрос.**

Так что ни `multi_query()`, ни `query()` для получения данных по id использовать нельзя.

Comment: Точно. А ведь вы правы, достаточно запросить `WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=5` ...        Почему же в мануале PHP опустили использование `more_results()` вместе с `next_result()` в их примере запроса `multi_query`: могут быть ситуации где он не используется или у них, как и у меня ранее, был отключен `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Comment: как-то вы пугающе выразились. Будьте добы, дайте примеры того, как использовать "плейсхолдеры являются единственно верным способом передавать переменные в запрос". Я прочитал на эту тему, вы имеете в виду список замены, видимо. Но, также, поясните почему "единственно верным". Очень любопытно.